# Как называется плашка под челкой на iOS устройствах?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

На некоторых сайтах на iOS есть такой фоновый цвет, который выступает под челкой. Как этот элемент называется и самое главное: **как его красить?** Результаты гугления по типу *"background color on header iOS"* и т.д. не дают никакого результата, инспектором в Safari тоже не получается найти этот цвет

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это задаётся через meta.

Пример, который учитывает тип темы, заданной на телефоне:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#319197" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#872e4e" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

Остальные возможности можете уже дополнительно посмотреть в документации.

Comment: Спасибо, и правда, Узнал так же, что можно задать theme-color через файл манифест